# Dealing with different ID cards

Tags: php, mysql, forms, unique

I'm making a form using PHP and MySQL and I need to register users that have different ID Cards (Some are organizations, other are from other countries; some are numerics other have letters) and I need that ID to be unique in order to in an easy way load the user data, but I don't know how to face up this situation.

I want to listen your expert advice to do in the best way as possible.

In the form sometimes one user refer to others, for example there is a field "sponsor" and the idea is to load the sponsor data only writing his ID.

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Please try to rephrase your question and provide more technical information.

Comment: @stslavik What other information do you need? I'm starting with this new form and before write it I want to plan how to do it. The idea is to make a 'Project Proposal Form' and I want to have only one table for users no matters if they are proposer, sponsor or partner.

Comment: @Memochipan: I suggest coming back when you've tried an approach ("My code looks like X, but is using these resources. Is there a better method to use instead of this convoluted regex?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not guarantee that numbers on ID-cards are unique across the whole world.
Your user table needs an ID-column that is separate from other data. An integer is usually fine.

You would then have to search using the card number and, in case of more than one hit, other attributes that are known about the customer.